# Flux parallel: only is taken one thread

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

This is my code:

```java
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

Flux.fromStream(...)
    .parallel()
    .runOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(new DelegatingSecurityContextExecutor(executor, SecurityContextHolder.getContext())))
    ...
    .sequential()
    .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .block();
```

As you can see, I'm trying to parallelize streams items.

However, I'm getting those logs:

```
2021-03-18 12:15:57.624 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:15:59.815 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:02.180 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:03.179 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:03.701 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:03.708 TRACE 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.a.i.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor
2021-03-18 12:16:03.710 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:03.884 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:04.665 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:04.760 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:04.777 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:04.789 TRACE 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.a.i.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor
2021-03-18 12:16:04.796 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:05.023 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:05.577 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:05.844 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:05.849 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:05.865 TRACE 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.a.i.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor
2021-03-18 12:16:05.875 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:06.225 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:06.759 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:06.897 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:06.911 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:06.932 TRACE 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.a.i.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor
2021-03-18 12:16:06.933 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:07.138 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:07.917 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:08.461 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:08.478 DEBUG 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.c.h.v.a.common.repository.HC3XMLDao
2021-03-18 12:16:08.481 TRACE 7076 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.a.i.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor
```

As you can see, all "tasks" are handled by one thread: `pool-2-thread-1`.

Nevertheless, my executor service has 10 threads.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is because you are using `.publishOn(Schedulers.single())` which merges the stream of multiple channels (when you set `.parallel()`) into one channel.

When I did this:

```
public class FluxAndMonoParallel {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FluxAndMonoParallel fluxAndMonoParallel = new FluxAndMonoParallel();
        fluxAndMonoParallel.parallel();
    }

    public void parallel() {
        Flux<Long> longFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .parallel()
                .runOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(executor))
                .sequential()
                .log();
        longFlux.subscribe();
    }
}
```

I have different threads been used and you can see that the reactor project is using `reactor.Flux.ParallelMergeSequential`.

```
12:37:52.196 [pool-1-thread-5] INFO reactor.Flux.ParallelMergeSequential.1 - onNext(0)
12:37:53.193 [pool-1-thread-6] INFO reactor.Flux.ParallelMergeSequential.1 - onNext(1)
12:37:54.193 [pool-1-thread-7] INFO reactor.Flux.ParallelMergeSequential.1 - onNext(2)
12:37:55.193 [pool-1-thread-8] INFO reactor.Flux.ParallelMergeSequential.1 - onNext(3)
12:37:56.193 [pool-1-thread-9] INFO reactor.Flux.ParallelMergeSequential.1 - onNext(4)
12:37:57.193 [pool-1-thread-10] INFO reactor.Flux.ParallelMergeSequential.1 - onNext(5)
12:37:58.193 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO reactor.Flux.ParallelMergeSequential.1 - onNext(6)
12:37:59.193 [pool-1-thread-3] INFO reactor.Flux.ParallelMergeSequential.1 - onNext(7)
12:38:00.193 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO reactor.Flux.ParallelMergeSequential.1 - onNext(8)
```

but when I use `fluxAndMonoParallel.sequential();` which resembles your example:

```
    public void sequential() {
        Flux<Long> longFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .parallel()
                .runOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(executor))
                .sequential()
                .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
                .log();
        longFlux.subscribe();
    }
```

I use only one thread:

```
12:38:59.719 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.PublishOn.1 - | request(unbounded)
12:39:00.733 [single-1] INFO reactor.Flux.PublishOn.1 - | onNext(0)
12:39:01.729 [single-1] INFO reactor.Flux.PublishOn.1 - | onNext(1)
12:39:02.729 [single-1] INFO reactor.Flux.PublishOn.1 - | onNext(2)
12:39:03.729 [single-1] INFO reactor.Flux.PublishOn.1 - | onNext(3)
12:39:04.729 [single-1] INFO reactor.Flux.PublishOn.1 - | onNext(4)
12:39:05.729 [single-1] INFO reactor.Flux.PublishOn.1 - | onNext(5)
12:39:06.728 [single-1] INFO reactor.Flux.PublishOn.1 - | onNext(6)
12:39:07.728 [single-1] INFO reactor.Flux.PublishOn.1 - | onNext(7)
12:39:08.729 [single-1] INFO reactor.Flux.PublishOn.1 - | onNext(8)
12:39:09.729 [single-1] INFO reactor.Flux.PublishOn.1 - | onNext(9)
```